# Was one of those that "turned" or "turn" to...?

Tags: tense

I think it should have been written "turned", right?

> It was one of those scheduled ten-minute meetings that **turn** into a two-hour meeting. [The New Yorker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand why the present tense is confusing, but it is not wrong.

The phrase "that turn into a two-hour meeting" is a relative clause describing "one of those scheduled ten-minute meetings" *in general*. Since the concept of a meeting that lasts too long is not limited to the time in the past when this specific meeting occurred, the present tense is appropriate. Consider this rewording:

> Do you know those scheduled ten-minute meetings that turn into two-hour meetings? This was one of those.

The past tense applies to this particular meeting, but the present tense applies to the description of these types of meetings in general.

---

However, the past tense could also work here. Either one is acceptable.